# PHPExcel how to use data from reader

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to understand how to get data from cells in PHPExcel but I have no idea. I read all documentation and I made this:

```
<?php
include('PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php');
class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter
{
    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
        // Read title row and rows 20 - 30
        if ($row == 1 || ($row >= 20 && $row <= 30)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$objReader->setReadFilter( new MyReadFilter() );
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("sample_mymails222.xlsx");
print_r($objPHPExcel);
?>
```

print_r show very big array.
I think there is some functions to get data from cell in $objPHPExcel.

How to do it?

Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the documentation chapter 4.5 (included in the PHPExcel download package)

Answer (score 25):

For anyone else who wants a more helpful answer, following the code in the example above, here is a quick snippet that will parse the active worksheet into a multi-dimensional array (this example ignores the ReadFilter that the OP created).

```php
$data =  array();
$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
  $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
  $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
  foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
    $data[$cell->getRow()][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getValue();
  }
}
var_dump($data);
```

BTW The reason I say "more helpful answer" is that I also had a hard time figuring out the PHPExcel documentation (which consists of 6 separate documents and no real API-like reference) the first time around.

The OP says he "read all the docs", but I am guessing that, like me, he read through the file called **PHPExcel User Documentation - Reading Spreadsheet Files.doc** which explains how to read in a spreadsheet, but does not cover using the contents.

To find that out, you have to dig into **PHPExcel developer documentation.doc** and get down to part 4 (which is where I found the example above).

Yup, my fault for not being thorough, but clearly this is a recurring issue. :-)

Comment: There is a full API reference in the /Documentation/API directory in the production distributions... it's amazing how many people are completely oblivious to its existence, despite the names of the directories

Comment: @MarkBaker PHPExcel is excellent! I cannot complaim about anything! I'd just give a sugestion (and I know you really don't need to do it), but I think people don't think it's easy to find the PHPExcel documentation because of the way it's being shown.In my opinion, Codeigniter's user guide is one of the best references of a great, clean and easy place to find all about codeigniter..The way you can search for information there, the examples,etc.In PHPExcel, it's a lil bit harder to do a search, but nothing really difficult. Almost all my questions here, I found the answer doing a better search

Answer (score 3):

for reading excel file you can use this

```html
require_once('PHPExcel.php');
$input_file_type = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($excel_file);
$obj_reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($input_file_type);
$obj_reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        
$objPHPExcel = $obj_reader->load($excel_file);
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$highest_row = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
$highest_col = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();
//$highest_col_index = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highest_col);
        
// start $row from 2, if you want to skip header
for ($counter = 2; $counter <= $highest_row; $counter++)
{
    $row = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A'.$counter.':'.$highest_col.$counter);
    $row = reset($row);            
}
```

Comment: I know its been a looong time since you posted this. But I cant find any help. How do I print the data in $row ? I always get `Undefined Offset`. PLease some help =\

Comment: Really thank you for answering dude. I just solved the problem, found a document.doc with some explanation... Thank you sir !! <3